# iOS: UIPasteboard returns array of NSData instead of UIImages on iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6

I am using `UIPasteboard` to access copied images.

```
UIPasteboard *pasteBoard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
NSArray *images = pasteBoard.images;
```

It is running fine on iOS 5 devices, the array contains `UIImage` objects.
On device running iOS 6 the array contains `NSData` objects instead. Is it known issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, after seeing your question I checked that and wondered that `pasteBoard.images` is returning the `NSData` array instead of `images`. So to get those images from data I used the below code and successfully got them:

```
UIPasteboard *pasteBoard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
NSArray *images = pasteBoard.images;
NSData *data = [images objectAtIndex:0];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
imageView.image = image;
```

If you copied more than one image then you would have to use a loop for getting all. So I think it should not be an issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, works great. There is no mention in the documentation about it so I think it is issue.